# Find the Ricci tensor from given product metric quickly

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am having trouble calculating the Ricci tensor. Suppose the product $I\times S^n$ has metric
$$g=dt^2+f^2(t)g_{S^{n}}$$
where $g_{S^{n}}$ is the standard metric on $S^{n}$, what is the Ricci tensor of this metric?
I have tried to do it for $n=2$ by writing the metric as
$$g=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&f^2&0\\0&0&f^2\sin^2\theta\end{pmatrix}$$
In a standard way, I calculated the Christoffel symbols and using the definition of Riemann tensor, of course, It is not wise to do similar thing in higher dimension. I am thinking that since the hypershpere is a manifold of constant sectional curvature 1 and the Ricci tensor is $$Ric=(n-1)g_{S^{n}}$$ Can we write the Ric on $I\times S^n$ from the Ric on $S^n$ and the product factor $f(t)$ quickly? But I don't know how to proceed. Any hint will be appreciated.